# Visual Studio database project - has an unresolved reference to object

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-project

I have imported a database "db_test" from SQL Server to my visual studio database project.

But when I compile this project, there is a lot of warning shown, saying procedure [sp_xxx] has an unresolved reference to object [db_test].[dbo].[table_1]. The stored procedure[sp_xxx] is also in database "db_test".

I have tried the suggested solution in below link, but the issue is still exist.

https://the.agilesql.club/2017/11/ssdt-how-to-fix-error-sql17502/

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565459/Fixing-SSDT-Unresolved-Reference-to-Object-Error

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the table `dbo.table_1` exist in your project?

Comment: yes, it exists.